# Fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

Tags: git, github

I am working through the ["Try Git"](http://try.github.com) tutorial.

When I get to the chapter "1.11 Pushing Remotely", and try to run:

```
$ git push -u orgin master
```

I get this error:

```
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've probably not added a public key to your SSH keys. Do that:

```
$ ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

Copy the created public key (`id_rsa.pub`) to your account's [list of SSH keys](https://github.com/settings/ssh), then try pushing again.

---

See the relevant help page: [Generating SSH Keys](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys) for a more in-depth response.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below command to get keys for the default account.

```
$ ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

More info: [Multiple SSH Keys settings for different github account](https://gist.github.com/jexchan/2351996)