# Permission denied (publickey) on BitBucket

Tags: git, ubuntu, bitbucket

I have strictly followed whole tutorial "[Set up SSH for Git and Mercurial on Mac OSX/Linux](https://confluence.atlassian.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=270827678)" on my Ubuntu Server 12 LTS. I have generated public key and added it to account settings on BitBucket site. In Ubuntu, if I type:

```
ssh -T git@bitbucket.org
```

I can see proper welcome message:

```
logged in as username.

You can use git or hg to connect to Bitbucket. Shell access is disabled.
```

But when I try to clone (or push) any repository:

```
Cloning into 'directory'...
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

What is the problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15240815/git-fatal-the-remote-end-hung-up-unexpectedly