# git push fails : Remote end hung up unexpectedly

Tags: github

I have created a git repository online in my account.
location : https://github.com/dinguluer/UiMagician

Now i cloned this repository on my pc. Then added the files to the project & pushed it, but it fails.

Error : Remote end hung up unexpectedly.

steps performed :--
git clone https://github.com/dinguluer/UiMagician
git add .
git commit -m "adding files "
git push"

How to push changes to git now.

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Git, fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15240815/git-fatal-the-remote-end-hung-up-unexpectedly)

Comment: this did not worked for me.

Comment: i tried both answers -- git remote add origin git@github.com:username/project.git ---- &  -- git config http.postBuffer 524288000 ... but both give same error to me.

Comment: git remote add origin git@github.com:dinguluer/UiMagican.git ... command gives error --- fatal : remote origin already exist