# Read from remote host: The connection was aborted

Tags: git

I can't push my commit to the remote when they are too large or with too many files.

I can `pull`:

```
P:\wamp\www>git pull
myuser@myserver.ovh.net's password:
Already up-to-date.
```

But I can't `push` :

```
P:\wamp\www>git push
myuser@myserver.ovh.net's password:
Counting objects: 170, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (31/31), done.
Writing objects: 100% (32/32), 767.20 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 32 (delta 24), reused 0 (delta 0)
Read from remote host myserver.ovh.net: The connection was aborted
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I've searched on google and here but [the solution of increasing git buffer doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15240815/git-fatal-the-remote-end-hung-up-unexpectedly).

For info,

```
P:\wamp\www>git remote -v
origin  ssh://myuser@myserver.ovh.net/home/myuser/repo (fetch)
origin  ssh://myuser@myserver.ovh.net/home/myuser/repo (push)
```

I've rebooted the VPS, same result.

After filmor comment, I've also tried `git push origin master` but `everything is up to date`.

EDIT : To clarify, I want to push a branch, but `git push origin mybranch` give me the same error message.

Comment: `git push origin master`?

Comment: @filmor : 'everything is up to date.'

Comment: Isn't that a good sign? :)

Comment: @filmor : no, I want to push a branch :( And when I do `git push origin mybranch` I get the same error message.

Comment: @filmor : I've done another test : made a new folder, cloned the distant repo in it, made a modification to the desired branch, pushed it. It worked (oO). Do you know what could be the difference here?

Comment: Erf... I tried to paste the local modifications from my original repo to this copy, commited the changes, and now I can't push it anymore to the distant repo :(

Comment: Well, are you sure that there's no an "input filter" which prevents the commits to be received? Technically such a behavior could be achieved if the remote end has a post-receive hook and this hook terminates abnormally (or at least "impolitely")

Comment: No, there isn't any input filter or hook on the remote server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a solution, I had to update my current branch in order to get rid of this error, occuring everytime my commits were too large:

```
git pull origin mybranch
```

After that, everything works fine.