# Can't commit Unity project to private Git without fatal error

Tags: git, unity-game-engine

I've been trying to commit my Unity game project to a private repository on Github with my Mac for a while, however it doesn't seem like that's possible as every time I've tried, it fails mid way through when I try to push. I'm an artist and have had trouble with git in the past, so I had my programmer friend look it over and attempt to do it via terminal yesterday. All was going well and it actually finished to 100%, but then this happened.

[image]

We're not sure what exactly the problem is. We do highly suspect that the project's size is a factor. My project is currently around 4 - 5GB in total, however I had this problem still back when it was less than that. He recommended I ask Stack Overflow, so here I am. Anyone have a clue what's going on?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Git, fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15240815/git-fatal-the-remote-end-hung-up-unexpectedly)

Answer (score 1):

When you push a large amount of data (initial push of a big repository, change with very big file(s)) may require a higher http.postBuffer setting on your git client (not the server)
For exemple :

```
git config --global http.postBuffer 157286400
```