# Git error - fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

Tags: git, command-line, ssh, cygwin

I'm trying to push to git but I keep getting the same issue. I tried the solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15240815/git-fatal-the-remote-end-hung-up-unexpectedly), but none seem to work. Please let me know what it could be.

```
$ git push origin master:master
Username for 'http://internalgit.lan':
Password for 'http://avandenheste@internalgit.lan':
Counting objects: 176, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (171/171), done.
Writing objects: 100% (176/176), 56.07 MiB | 4.87 MiB/s, done.
Total 176 (delta 49), reused 0 (delta 0)
error: RPC failed; result=22, HTTP code = 413
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date
```

Answer (score 0):

What it is, is that you're sending a (too) large object via http.

> **413 - Request entity too large**
>   The server is refusing to process a request because the request entity is larger than the server is willing or able to process.

To fix it I can think of two options:

1. Start using `ssh` instead of `http`. This is the best option if ssh is available for you to use.
2. Configure the web-server handling the request to accept larger requests.