# The remote end hung up unexpectedly VisualStudioTeamservice

Tags: git, azure-devops

When push the code to visualstudioTeamservice,I met the problem 'The remote end hung up unexpectedly' as below:

[image]

I try to solve it as here mentioned:

> `git remote rm origin` then try again

And

> `git config http.postBuffer 524288000`

But no effect,Who can give me a hand?Thanks

Comment: you probably don't have access to push to the repo, or your remote url has the wrong protocol see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15240815/git-fatal-the-remote-end-hung-up-unexpectedly

Comment: @bjhaid I try with the answers