# Unable to push the changes to Git remote repository when using Apache Traffic Server proxy

Tags: git, github, apache-traffic-server

I'm trying to push the changes to Git remote repository, but got ended with following error message -

> error: RPC failed; HTTP 500 curl 22 The requested URL returned error:
> 500 INKApi  Error fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly fatal:
> The remote end hung up unexpectedly Everything up-to-date

I have followed the steps below till now -

1. Made required configuration to clone the package

> git config --global http.proxy
> http://mydomain\myusername:mypassword@myproxyserver:8080

2. Cloned the repository using following line -

> git clone http://mypackageurl

3. Made some changes in existing method and saved the file
4. Then executed following commands to add, commit & push

> git add testpath/updatedfile.py

> git commit -m "Updating sample script"

> git push

> git push origin master

But no luck, getting same error mentioned above.

Git clone was successful, didn't face any issue in that. While trying to push the change only getting HTTP 500 error. And I've installed GitHub desktop application and trying all these stuffs through Git Shell

Comment: `git clone http://mypackageurl` usually you cannot push over http, error says that your server responses 500 (internal server error), so check server logs for anything suspicious. Which git repo manager do you use?

Comment: As I remember, the http is read-only protocol, you could clone, but could not push.

Comment: Yes, git http was read-only. According to this link : https://git-scm.com/book/tr/v2/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols#The-HTTP-Protocols
Git can communicate over HTTP in two different modes. Prior to Git 1.6.6 there was only one way it could do this which was very simple and generally read-only.

Comment: Cool... now it's clear that HTTP would allow two way communication. But could someone please help me in resolving the HTTP 500 error?

Answer (score 16):

Github itself may be down also. The status of GitHub can be observed at https://www.githubstatus.com/.

Comment: Objectivly, this answer isn't very good even if it's real

Comment: As far as I can tell, the question is not actually about github. the error message the asker is getting indicates a relation to the apache traffic server proxy.

Answer (score 8):

Increase the Git buffer size to the largest individual file size of your repo:

```
git config --global http.postBuffer 157286400
```

**http.postBuffer**

Maximum size in bytes of the buffer used by smart HTTP transports when POSTing data to the remote system. For requests larger than this buffer size, HTTP/1.1 and Transfer-Encoding: chunked is used to avoid creating a massive pack file locally. Default is 1 MiB, which is sufficient for most requests.

Comment: If you are sure that this is the cause of the error, then I'd suggest marking this question as a duplicate of [Git, fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15240815/11107541), where a similar answer already exists (though it might help if you improved it there :) ). However, I'm inclined to believe the problem is related to their proxy, since the error message includes a portion that seems specific to Apache Traffic Server.

Answer (score 0):

I am running Gitlab Community Edition version 8.10.6. To solve this issue I changed two params in my /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb configuration file. I show the default values in the commended rows.

```
# gitlab_rails['git_max_size'] = 20971520
gitlab_rails['git_max_size'] = 524288000

# nginx['client_max_body_size'] = '250m'
 nginx['client_max_body_size'] = '0'
```

After that I run the above commands (the second is optional),

```
gitlab-ctl reconfigure
gitlab-ctl restart
```

Answer (score 0):

First, i tried and i get the same Error.

But i went to the config Project in Gitlab, and i add my email to members in project, and after i changed the SSH url to HTTPS i make again the git remote add and it works

Answer (score 0):

I know github is down right now, but somehow this works for me everytime I try to push.

```sh
git pull --rebase
git push
```