# Is it possible in git to push commits one by one instead of all of them at once?

Tags: git, push, commit

I'm using a really unreliable connection and while I try to stage commits so none of them is over 20mb and/or to push them once they reach a size like that, sometimes it's not possible (a few of the assets can be big - I know it's not the best idea to use git for assets too) and there are 90% of chances my connection will fail before everything is sent.

Is it possible to push commits one by one, or can you suggest any other tips that could be useful for this case?

Comment: Question: You do know that a commit only saves the changes between it and the previous commit right? 10 commits where you added one 10 MB file does not equate to 100 MB. And if you change one line of that 10 MB file, git will store a record of only that line changing.

Comment: Out of curiosity... What are you storing in your git repo that is so large?

Answer (score 14):

Yes, it's not only possible but in fact pretty trivial.  Instead of:

```
git push remote branch
```

just run:

```
git push remote <commit-hash>:branch
```

once for each commit to try pushing, in the appropriate (parent-most to child-most) order.

To automate this, assuming your remote is named `origin` and your branch is named `branch` and your `origin/branch` remote-tracking branch is up to date (run `git fetch origin` if not):

```
for rev in $(git rev-list --reverse origin/branch..branch); do
    git push origin $rev:branch;
done
```

which is really a one-liner split into three lines for StackOverflow posting purposes.  (Note: this also assumes a more or less linear history; add `--topo-order` to guarantee things if not, but then you'll need `--force` and there are various bad ideas occurring here, so that's not the way to go: you'd want to split the pushes to use a temporary branch, or aggregate them at the merge points, perhaps.)

Comment: What if this is a new local branch that doesn't exist on the remote?

Comment: @StevenShaw: in that case, you must choose your starting-point commit manually. We're using `origin/branch` above in the `<exclude>..branch` expression because we know it's a commit that the remote already has, so that the first `git push` starts with the first commit reachable *after* that point, which is probably the first commit that `origin` lacks. Once you have found the appropriate starting point, you can either use `git push` to create `origin/branch`, or create it manually, after which the above code fragment will work.

Comment: In case that wasn't clear (I'm not sure): `origin/branch` is a local name that holds your own Git's memory of `branch` on the remote. If we don't have it, we can't use it *yet*. We can use it once we create it. We can create it in multiple different ways. We only *need* it to kick off the whole process, so if your connection is reliable—if you don't have to restart this series of `git push`-es frequently—you could just write `for rev in $(git rev-list --reverse <hash>..branch); do ...`. But if your connection is reliable, you don't need any of this in the first place.

Comment: Thanks, I had switch the "from" to `origin/master` as in `git rev-list --reverse origin/master..branch`. The only problem was that the remote branch did not exist so the `git push` would fail because the remote ref didn't exist. I don't know how to create an "empty" remote branch without pushing my local branch (which would defeat the purpose of pushing commits 1-by-1).

Comment: @StevenShaw: `origin/master` will often work, but might require a force-push to get the "real" commits started. `git merge-base origin/master branch` would be a better starting point: `git push -u origin $(git merge-base origin/master branch):refs/heads/branch` would create `origin/branch` in your local repository and set that as the upstream of `branch`, after which the one-by-one pushes will work.

Answer (score 3):

Just to clarify the other answer:

```sh
git push <remote name> <commit SHA>:<remote branch name>
```

Example:

```sh
git push origin c01c4fa28a0c864c2d09f8fb43a80c46dce9c7c6:master
```