# Cannot push project to github

Tags: git, github, large-files

I am trying to push an unreal project to github. It is a very big repo, >12 GB. Everytime I try and push using SSL, I get the following stuff and repo does not push.

```
Enumerating objects: 990, done.
Counting objects: 100% (990/990), done.
Delta compression using up to 6 threads
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
Connection to github.com closed by remote host.
Compressing objects: 100% (945/945), done.
fatal: sha1 file '<stdout>' write error: Broken pipe
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Any tips?

Comment: https://github.community/t/constant-fatal-the-remote-end-hung-up-unexpectedly-when-pushing-to-new-repositories/1714/12

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error several times. The error was on my end as my internet disconnected. My tip (and how I fixed it): revert your last (or initial) commit, which contains the 12GB data (not a revert commit!). After that, split your project into smaller projects by staging only single folders of your project. Than try to push only one commit at a time (for further information, look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45155607/4613465)).