# Failed to push existing local git repository

Tags: git, github

I'm pretty new to GitHub. When I try to push my local project to a git repository, it fails all the time.

So I've created a new repository on git without having a readme.md
https://github.com/winswang/comp_holo_video

I navigate to the local git folder I want to upload code.
I configure the buffer to be very large. (I also deleted some data from my original folder)

```
git config --global http.postBuffer 157286400
```

then I used

```
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/winswang/comp_holo_video.git
```

(I also tried add, the results are the same), and then

```
git push -u origin master
```

Then error occurs:

```
Counting objects: 86, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (84/84), done.
error: RPC failed; curl 55 SSL_write() returned SYSCALL, errno = 32
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
Writing objects: 100% (86/86), 4.23 GiB | 17.85 MiB/s, done.
Total 86 (delta 26), reused 1 (delta 0)
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: What happens when you try with the default buffer size?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Error code**: [CURLE_SEND_ERROR (55)](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html). Failed sending network data. This is due to network issues.

**How to troubleshoot?**

try this command `git fsck` and see does it reports any error.

---

There might be two issues one your repo size is greater 1gb and secondly, your network connection is slow. Perhaps try to increase the buffer size furthermore.

Try `git config --global http.postBuffer 524288000`

HTTPS has the problem in handling the big files and you cant push files with the size more than 1gb.

See this for more info about the issue. [curl ssl_write error=55](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bbkb/error-rpc-failed-result-55-http-code-0-301663267.html)

---

The simple straightforward solution is to switch it to the ssh that will solve the problem.

[Switching from https to ssh.](https://help.github.com/articles/changing-a-remote-s-url/)

---

**Addition info**

GitHub will warn you when pushing files larger than 50 MB. You will not be allowed to push files larger than 100 MB.

---

**GIT LFS**

You can use Git Large File Storage (Git LFS) as part of your workflow. Git LFS works well with the GitHub Flow and can be used with any large file, regardless of its type.

For more information, [see versioning large files](https://help.github.com/articles/conditions-for-large-files/)

Answer (score 0):

It could be that HTTPS remote is not stable enough to handle a large initial push. Could you try using SSH instead?

See [Git, fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15240815/git-fatal-the-remote-end-hung-up-unexpectedly)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have an internet connection issue or some large files included in your commit.You should do push several times in some intervals, or increase buffer size and then try to push again?

git config --global http.postBuffer 314572800