# git push --force fail

Tags: git, push, bfg-repo-cleaner

I had recently did some clean up of my repo as it had some large files in the history. I had use BFG to clean up, did the necessary steps as mentioned here [here](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/#usage). At the final steps when doing the git push to publish the updated changes, it fails. Error Message:

```
$ git push --force
Enumerating objects: 4767, done.
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://my/personal/repo.git'
```

Some additional info:

1. I did the clean up in a not bare repo
2. I currently had trouble pulling the repo as it is over 2G already hence wanted to clean up some image files that I accidently push up to the remote repo.
3. There are several other people using the repo and I would like to do the clean up in a way that minimize disruption to their work.
4. Currently, all of us are pulling the lastest commit and working from there by this command:

   `git clone -b dev https://my/personal/repo.git --depth=1`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git, fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15240815/git-fatal-the-remote-end-hung-up-unexpectedly)

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that this is not specific to the branch you're pushing.

`fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly` is more connectivity or authentication type of issue.

Do you have a non cleaned up version of the repo? You could try to push there to confirm the setup is correct.

Comment: yes my remote repo is a non cleaned up version. I was actually trying to push the cleaned up version to this repo but got this error.