# Cannot clone RISC-V toolchain

Tags: git, riscv

When I try to recursively clone the `riscv-tools` using the following command:

```
git clone https://github.com/riscv/riscv-tools.git --recursive
```

I get this error:

```
error: RPC failed; curl 18 transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed
fatal: clone of 'https://github.com/riscv/riscv-glibc.git' into submodule path '/home/joe/riscv-tools/riscv-gnu-toolchain/riscv-glibc' failed
Failed to clone 'riscv-glibc'. Retry scheduled
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I was able to execute that command without any errors. Based on the `fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly` bit, I'd bet network errors are to blame. Did all retries fail?

Comment: Yes all retries have failed. I have run the command a few times over the last couple of days and I always get the same error.

Comment: Looks like [a prior answer about git/https buffer settings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15851500/6571327). Based on [the git-config docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config-httppostBuffer) it seems like this's a promising lead.  Could you set `git config http.postBuffer 524288000` and retry the action?

Comment: Thanks for the help but I have already tried adjusting the buffer size and, unfortunately, it didn't work.

Comment: Why aren't you calling `git submodule update --init --recursive` after cloning the repository? Just curious...

Comment: I thought cloning it with the recursive tag would do the same thing? I am new to this.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I fixed the problem by changing my DNS IP address to `8.8.8.8`. I have not idea why this worked but for some reason it did.