# Stuck in a git commit

Tags: git

I have added several files by mistake with

```
git add <file name>
```

Then I have run

```
git commit -m '..'
```

However, some files where too big and it failed when I run git push - now I'm stuck and I can't unstage those big files.

I've tried with 'git reset', 'git rm' but every time I try to push these big files reappear!
How do I reset everything?

Comment: Could you run 'git status' and show us the output?

Comment: If the commit succeeded (`git log` shows the new entry), `git reset HEAD^` will uncommit it without touching the working tree.

Comment: git reset HEAD^ doesn't work. when I push again these big files are still there

Comment: Were those files first added in the most recent commit?

Comment: yes - since I've added I haven't been able to get rid of them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove/delete a large file from commit history in Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100907/how-to-remove-delete-a-large-file-from-commit-history-in-git-repository)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+remove+large+files+history

Comment: How big are those files that are stuck, you can try this: `git config http.postBuffer 524288000`. This sets the buffer size to 500mb, this might help in pushing those big files to the repo. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15851500/7639034) is a stackoverflow answer that might help you solve this.

Answer (score 1):

Normally what you do in this cases is amend the revision you created to remove the files..... so if you have created revisions after that revision where you added thenm, it won't work because those files are already part of the history of the project.... so, go back to the revision where you added them by mistake (use the ID), rm --cache those files and amend. Then you could push into the remote.

```
git checkout id-of-the-revision-where-I-added-the-files
git rm --cache file1 file2 file3 etc
git commit --amend --no-edit
# if everything is fine, move the branch pointer and push
git branch -f my-branch
git checkout my-branch
git push some-remote my-branch
```

That should be good enough