# fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly Everything up-to-date

Tags: git, github

I am trying to commit a folder in my repo with `3342` files of `8.0 MB` each.

```
git commit -m 'add my folder'
git push -u origin master
Counting objects: 3342, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (3342/3342), done.
error: RPC failed; curl 55 SSL_write() returned SYSCALL, errno = 32
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
Writing objects: 100% (3342/3342), 3.77 GiB | 2.48 MiB/s, done.
Total 3342 (delta 2241), reused 0 (delta 0)
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

But it returns

```
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

If I try the solution proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15240815/git-fatal-the-remote-end-hung-up-unexpectedly) to swhitch to `ssh`

```
git remote add origin git@github.com:username/project.git
```

I get:

```
fatal: remote origin already exists.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git, fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15240815/git-fatal-the-remote-end-hung-up-unexpectedly)

Comment: I tried but I get `fatal: remote origin already exists.`

Comment: Read all the answers, `git config http.postBuffer 524288000` this might be helpful.

Comment: @Code_Ninja ok I will try

Comment: did it solve the issue?

Comment: @Code_Ninja trying

Comment: @Code_Ninja still getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

As to the error

```
fatal: remote origin already exists.
```

you may want to remove your existing remote (called origin by default) or rename it. Inspect the available remotes with `git remote -v` and consult `git help remote` for the correct rename/delete commands. Of course, another way would be to adjust the suggested command

```
git remote add origin git@github.com:username/project.git
```

and replace origin by an alternative name (e.g., ori-github). Then you would have to work with this origin name in future commands.