# I can do push the code to the remote directory but cant deploy the same stuff in Heroku! how could that be possible?

Tags: heroku, deployment, push

I am trying to deploy app into heroku, I have something already there but when I push the latest changes, I come with this issue:

```
  Sujan-MacBook-Pro:Server sujan$ git push origin master
Everything up-to-date
Sujan-MacBook-Pro:Server sujan$ git push heroku master
Enumerating objects: 161, done.
Counting objects: 100% (161/161), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (144/144), done.
fatal: unable to read 92026926ffb357dc78360aa8695e5d6e4e0d5542
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/morning-waters-83286.git'
Sujan-MacBook-Pro:Server sujan$ 
Sujan-MacBook-Pro:Server sujan$ 
Sujan-MacBook-Pro:Server sujan$ git config --global http.postBuffer 157286400
Sujan-MacBook-Pro:Server sujan$ git push heroku master
Enumerating objects: 161, done.
Counting objects: 100% (161/161), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (144/144), done.
fatal: unable to read 92026926ffb357dc78360aa8695e5d6e4e0d5542
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/morning-waters-83286.git'
Sujan-MacBook-Pro:Server sujan$ git fsck
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
missing blob 92026926ffb357dc78360aa8695e5d6e4e0d5542
```

There seems to be missing blob but none of the things could solve the issue!!!

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied and offer poor usability. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: It seems like you may have something indexed in git that is missing or corrupted on disk. What does `git fsck` show? https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fsck

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git, fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15240815/git-fatal-the-remote-end-hung-up-unexpectedly)