# Git push returning an error when pushing?

Tags: git, github

```
pavan@Pavans-Air link-dashboard % git push origin feat/orders
Enumerating objects: 103, done.
Counting objects: 100% (103/103), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (68/68), done.
Writing objects: 100% (72/72), 134.83 KiB | 4.49 MiB/s, done.
Total 72 (delta 35), reused @ (delta 6)
error: RPC failed; curl 92 HTTP/2 stream @ was not closed cleanly: PROTOCOL_ERROR (err 1)
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date
```

I am getting this error when I am pushing the code to my GitHub.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git, fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15240815/git-fatal-the-remote-end-hung-up-unexpectedly)

Comment: Please do not post images of text, _just include the text_. Please also include whatever is relevant from `.git/config`.

Answer (score 1):

Is probably an authentication problem. **Try using `ssh` instead of `http`.**

You change the origin of the current repository with `git remote`.

```
git remote add origin git@github.com:username/project.git
```

Or you can also set `ssh` as a default over `html` globally.

**GitHub**

```
git config --global url.ssh://git@github.com/.insteadOf https://github.com/
```

**Bitbucket**

```
git config --global url.ssh://git@bitbucket.org/.insteadOf https://bitbucket.org/
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi to any other person experiencing this. I actually tried all the solutions I saw on stackoverflow and github and none worked.
All I had to do was restart my laptop and try again and it worked. Like Magic