# Pushing to GitHub issue - HTTP/2 stream 0 was not closed cleanly: CANCEL (err 8)

Tags: git, github

Trying to commit my code to GitHub, never had an issues before and I've gone through all quick fixes but no luck so far. The error:

```
Enumerating objects: 10, done.                                                  
Counting objects: 100% (10/10), done.                                           
Delta compression using up to 16 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (6/6), done.                                          
Writing objects: 100% (6/6), 2.19 MiB | 33.00 MiB/s, done.                      
Total 6 (delta 3), reused 0 (delta 0)
error: RPC failed; curl 92 HTTP/2 stream 0 was not closed cleanly: CANCEL (err 8)
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date
```

I've had a look around at these issues:

1. [Git push returning an error when pushing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59101163/git-push-returning-an-error-when-pushing)
2. [Git, fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15240815/git-fatal-the-remote-end-hung-up-unexpectedly)

And I've updated my buffer with `git config http.postBuffer 524288000`, but my issue seems to relate to a `CANCEL (err 8)` whereas the others are either protocol errors or HTTP/2 issues.

Any ideas on how I could get GitHub pushing working again? I've never had any issues with pushing to Github until today, and I made 2 commits about 30 minutes before that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The issue seemed to be caused by slow internet speeds. Perhaps what I reported was a timeout error.

It wasn't clear to me what specifically fixed it, but moving to another location with faster internet resolved this issue.

I still welcome any other suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you tried to upload file sizes that were too large. Try uploading files partially or upload smaller files. I was faced with this problem and this method helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to download the files but experienced some issues (see below) and needed to try a couple of times - used read_csv (readr) as read.csv didn't work

```
> data_3 <- read_csv("https://storage.covid19datahub.io/level/3.csv")    # download the data
Rows: 6993673 Columns: 47                                                                 
 0s── Column specification ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
Delimiter: ","
chr  (13): id, administrative_area_level_1, administrative_area_level_2, administrative_...
dbl  (32): confirmed, deaths, recovered, tests, vaccines, people_vaccinated, people_full...
lgl   (1): vent
date  (1): date

ℹ Use `spec()` to retrieve the full column specification for this data.
ℹ Specify the column types or set `show_col_types = FALSE` to quiet this message.
Warning message:
One or more parsing issues, see `problems()` for details 
> problems()
# A tibble: 6,094 × 5
      row   col expected           actual file 
    <int> <int> <chr>              <chr>  <chr>
 1 425027    12 1/0/T/F/TRUE/FALSE 7      ""   
 2 425028    12 1/0/T/F/TRUE/FALSE 5      ""   
 3 425029    12 1/0/T/F/TRUE/FALSE 6      ""   
 4 425030    12 1/0/T/F/TRUE/FALSE 8      ""   
 5 425031    12 1/0/T/F/TRUE/FALSE 13     ""   
 6 425032    12 1/0/T/F/TRUE/FALSE 17     ""   
 7 425033    12 1/0/T/F/TRUE/FALSE 21     ""   
 8 425034    12 1/0/T/F/TRUE/FALSE 25     ""   
 9 425035    12 1/0/T/F/TRUE/FALSE 27     ""   
10 425036    12 1/0/T/F/TRUE/FALSE 35     ""   
# … with 6,084 more rows
```

Comment: I don't really understand how this is related to the question.

Comment: I just wanted to state that there might be heavy traffic at the github hindering download and that it is important to use the reader version of read_csv

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue but none of the answers helped for me. Git itself suggested the following and it worked fine <git push --set-upstream URL master>

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: after this everything worked even for git push url master

Answer (score -1):

$ git config --global http.version HTTP/1

Comment: A good answer will always include an explanation why this would solve the issue, so that the OP and any future readers can learn from it.

Answer (score -1):

```
git config http.postBuffer 524288000
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?