# Can't push to remote branch properly

Tags: git

I am trying to push to my remote branch but I got this error:

```
hello@ThemChum wanoca % git push origin dev
Enumerating objects: 80, done.
Counting objects: 100% (80/80), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (62/62), done.
Writing objects: 100% (68/68), 10.55 MiB | 415.49 MiB/s, done.
Total 68 (delta 18), reused 35 (delta 1)
error: RPC failed; curl 92 HTTP/2 stream 0 was not closed cleanly: PROTOCOL_ERROR (err 1)
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date
```

[image]

**Note: I checked the folder files sizes it's not even 1 MB.**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Git, fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15240815/git-fatal-the-remote-end-hung-up-unexpectedly)

Comment: @dahiya_boy I used https instead of ssh.

Comment: I had the same issue trying to push too many files at once. The corporate connection to the remote was interrupted by some IT security configurations

Answer (score 0):

If you are using HTTPS, you would need either a certificate signed by a certification authority, or if the remote server is in your network, you could use a self signed certificate.

Git mentions there is very little advantage of using HTTPS instead of SSH, from the following article.

https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols