# Issue with Git "fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly"

Tags: git, github, fatal-error, git-push

I have am facing issues while pushing my code to git here are things i have tried so far

- Clear Cache and then push.
- Delete the .git folder and re init the code to master.
- Increase the postBuffer to "100000000"  `git config http.postBuffer 100000000`
- Unlink the local repo and link it to a new repo
- Create a New local folder, move the code into new folder and then try push it last 2 repo's(original / second copy)
- Create a New local folder, move the code into new folder and push it the fresh repo
- Use git desktop to push the code repeating the previous steps

No matter what i always get this same error, Here is the excate error i got in my last attempt.

```
Enumerating objects: 217, done.
Counting objects: 100% (217/217), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (211/211), done.
Writing objects: 100% (217/217), 10.77 MiB | 14.50 MiB/s, done.
Total 217 (delta 22), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
error: RPC failed; curl 18 transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date
```

**This issue is happening specifically for this particular repo / code.**

**When i try to push any other repos they work fine.**

**Also originally i was able to push to heroku whereas git always failed. Same thing with the fresh copies as well**

Any Suggestions

EDIT1:

Well as a last resort i switched from my WIFI to Mobile data, to test the thoery that the issue may be realtred with my ISP blocking certain github server / IP, and to my surprise it went through and i was able to commit my code, thing is my mobile data is way slower due to mobile conntivity compared to my Wifi which is like 20+mbps.. so it cannot be said that the speed was the issue between these to ISP's, so as a quick conculsion i think my Wifi ISP is blocking the github website or some of its Ip address (i say this because some of my repo are getting updated but this particular one is not and this same particular repo can be updated via mobile data.)

Comment: Try increasing buffer size to 524288000. 
Also please see this https://stackoverflow.com/q/15240815/6309111

Comment: Did that still not change.. 
`git config http.postBuffer 524288000`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a last resort, I switched from my WiFi to mobile data in order to test the theory that the issue may be with my ISP. After this change, the commit went through!

I am not sure what happened there, as my mobile data is far slower. To even call it 3G would be an understatement, and yet, somehow, it worked.

I tried method again today as well, and it seemed to work. I still do not have a permanent fix, or even a good explanation, but at least this is a workaround.

Comment: I am surprised that this worked for me too

Comment: Yeah, it has always worked I faced this issue several times and this approach gets the job done. Still haven't been able to find out why & how

Answer (score 1):

How I resolved this error,thou strange but it worked for me, i switched to the version 1.1 using this command  "git config --global http.version HTTP/1.1" and then switched back to version 2 using this command  "git config --global http.version HTTP/2" and then i tried pushing again and it was successful. not sure what happened in between.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this, I tried a lot of different solutions but only this one allows me to proceed!
It would be great to find out why it helps :)

Comment: I'm glad it helped you.  I'll look into it and see if I can find out what changed.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the following commands worked:

```
git config --global http.postBuffer 1048576000
git config --global http.lowSpeedLimit 0
git config --global http.lowSpeedTime 999999
```