# I can't push a GitHub commit - RPC failed; curl 55 Send failure: Connection was aborted

Tags: git, github, push, git-push

I'm trying to push a commit I've already done in GitHub.

But I can't. When I press push (or I put `git push` in cmd), i get the following error:

```
Enumerating objects: 78, done.
Counting objects: 100% (78/78), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (37/37), done.
error: RPC failed; curl 55 Send failure: Connection was aborted
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
Writing objects: 100% (48/48), 11.72 MiB | 339.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 48 (delta 23), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date
```

It's a C++ program wrote with VS. I've already commited and pushed more things in the same repo and the same project. The repo is https://github.com/Tupiet/learncpp-tutorial

I've been searching for a while and I find people saying to do this: `git config --global http.version HTTP/1.1`. Already done, but it's still not working. I've also find other articles in this forum, but anyone of the answers has worked in my case. I'm a bit worried about if I had to re-start the GitHub repo, because I can't find any solution.

Do you know how to solve it? I'll be really grateful if you could help me, it's sad doing this a lot of times and just now it doesn't work.

Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15240815/git-fatal-the-remote-end-hung-up-unexpectedly

Comment: Wow, thanks! Doing `git config http.postBuffer 524288000` just solved it. Sorry for stealing your time, and really thanks for losing a bit of time asking me. Thanks!

Comment: That `http.postBuffer` had any effect means you have [something seriously broken on your network or computer](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#Documentation/gitfaq.txt-WhatdoescodehttppostBuffercodereallydo).  It could be a proxy, antivirus, or firewall, but the thing to do is fix that instead of using `http.postBuffer`.

Comment: Oh, that doesn't look good. There's any way I can see what's exactly broken? Thanks for taking your time to answer me!