# Couldn't push to github

Tags: git

Could you help me to figure out - how I can resolve this issue? It's a pet project and I'm using a terminal in VSC

```
Enumerating objects: 133, done.
    Counting objects: 100% (133/133), done.
    Delta compression using up to 4 threads
    Compressing objects: 100% (118/118), done.
    error: RPC failed; curl 55 SSL_write() returned SYSCALL, errno = 10053
    atal: the remote end hung up unexpectedlyB | 10.00 KiB/s   
    Writing objects: 100% (118/118), 258.56 MiB | 926.00 KiB/s, done.
    Total 118 (delta 65), reused 0 (delta 0)
    fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
    Everything up-to-date
```

The result: still 20 commits are remain

What can be done?

P.s. Probably - the problem I have is that the changes are made in the video in the project - so they are heavy and my upload speed is very low

Comment: Try pushing again?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Git, fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15240815/git-fatal-the-remote-end-hung-up-unexpectedly)