# Not able to push commits to remote repo with git push

Tags: git, github, push

Here is what I get when I am trying to push to a remote repo

```
*$ git push origin main

Enumerating objects: 437, done.

Counting objects: 100% (437/437), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (371/371), done.
Writing objects: 100% (396/396), 1.71 MB | 3.77 MB/s, done.
Total 396 (delta 57), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
error: RPC failed; curl 18 transfer closed with outstanding read 
data remaining
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly*
```

I used `$git config http.postBuffer 524288000` but got same results.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15240815/

Comment: See [the Git FAQ](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#http-postbuffer) for why you shouldn't need to change `http.postBuffer` and the problems it can cause.