# github push error for my big update: rpc failed

Tags: git, git-push

I pushed a big update for my repo. But I have got a problem... I tried to solve it but I couldn't find a solution. The error in the bellow:

```
> git push origin main:main
error: RPC failed; curl 18 transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining
send-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date
```

I actually do not know why is that problem happening. But I think the problem couses of trying to push very big data.

Comment: one better way is to push the data in chunks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15240815/git-fatal-the-remote-end-hung-up-unexpectedly