# Move a Gitea repo to a new one

Tags: git, gitea

I couldn't clone a git repo from my Gitea server:

```
Klone nach 'diss' ...
Username for 'https://git.ursliska.de': uliska
Password for 'https://uliska@git.ursliska.de': 
remote: Zähle Objekte: 7403, Fertig.
remote: Komprimiere Objekte: 100% (4377/4377), Fertig.
fatal: Die Gegenseite hat unerwartet abgebrochen.
fatal: zu frühes Dateiende/7403)
fatal: index-pack fehlgeschlagen
```

A friend found out that it was an issue with the repo itslf (I could clone other repos without errors), and he managed to "fake" clonig by producing an archive on the server and downloading and unpacking it on my computer, where I now have a complete working tree without a proper Git repository holding it. Our idea was t create a new empty server and push te local code to that. Even though that wold lose all history info it would be a huge gain.

To achieve this I'd have to init a Git repo and commit the whole content (in one single commit, I fear) in order to later be able to do the `git push -u` thing. Is there a convenient way t recursively stage all files in a working tree?

Comment: It might also be a firewall issue. Is https traffic allowed from your machine to the server? Is that domain blocked?

Comment: Maybe the SSL certificate has problems?

Comment: Similar issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15240815/git-fatal-the-remote-end-hung-up-unexpectedly

Comment: From Atlassian (a git GUI): https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserverkb/git-clone-fails-fatal-the-remote-end-hung-up-unexpectedly-fatal-early-eof-fatal-index-pack-failed-779171803.html