# ERROR; fatal: the remote end hung up unepectedly

Tags: llvm

I want to install LLVM on ubuntu runing by VMware, but I get this error all the time:

```
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed
```

or it just stays on 11% of receiving llvm and doesn't receive more.

I recently started LLVM and I don't know much about it.

I try all commands recommended at this post:
[Git, fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15240815/git-fatal-the-remote-end-hung-up-unexpectedly)

Comment: It sounds like your connection is timing out. How is your internet signal?

Comment: it is fluctuating!

Comment: I changed internet connection, and the problem solved. thank you so much

Comment: it looks like unstable connection. Try to use different mirror, example: `git clone https://mirrors.tuna.ajou.ac.kr/git/llvm-project.git`. It uses the Ajou university mirror